# Dynamic video streaming using vlc

Tags: vlc, mpeg-dash

I wish to perform adaptive bitrate streaming using VLC. The method which I am using is capturing a video using USB camera, encoding it and creating an MPD file with different birates so that VLC will be able to stream the video on client machine based on the quality of bandwidth. But VLC is not able to switch between the bandwidths while I tried playing the MPD file using "http://IPaddress:80/mpd_file.mpd".

Here is the part of MPD file

```
   <Representation id="v1" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.42C01E" width="3840" height="2160" frameRate="30" sar="1:1" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="6000000.000000">
   </Representation>
   <Representation id="v2" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.42C01E" width="1920" height="1080" frameRate="30" sar="1:1" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="8000000.000000">
   </Representation>
```

The following is the log message I'm getting in VLC when trying to switch the bandwidth from 6 Mbps to 8 Mbps

```
main debug: using opengl module "egl_x11"
main debug: looking for glconv module matching "any": 3 candidates
glconv_vaapi_x11 error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
main debug: using glconv module "glconv_vaapi_drm"
main debug: using vout display module "gl"
main debug: original format sz 3840x2160, of (0,0), vsz 3840x2160, 4cc VAOP, sar 1:1, msk r0x0 g0x0 b0x0
main debug: removing module "freetype"
main debug: looking for text renderer module matching "any": 3 candidates
freetype debug: Building font databases.
freetype debug: Took -11968 microseconds
main debug: using text renderer module "freetype"
main debug: looking for hw decoder module matching "any": 3 candidates
main debug: using hw decoder module "vaapi"
main debug: Received first picture
main debug: Decoder wait done in 296 ms
main debug: creating demux: access='' demux='mp4' location='' file='(null)'
main debug: looking for demux module matching "mp4": 56 candidates
adaptive debug: Retrieving http://10.75.28.48:80/Dash_Disp1-Zone1/v2_2_gpac.m4s @0
mp4 debug: dumping root Box "root"
mp4 debug: | + ftyp size 24 offset 0
mp4 debug: | + free size 66 offset 24
mp4 debug: | + moov size 677 offset 90
mp4 debug: | | + mvhd size 108 offset 98
mp4 debug: | | + mvex size 56 offset 206
mp4 debug: | | | + mehd size 16 offset 214
mp4 debug: | | | + trex size 32 offset 230
mp4 debug: | | + trak size 505 offset 262
mp4 debug: | | | + tkhd size 92 offset 270
mp4 debug: | | | + mdia size 405 offset 362
mp4 debug: | | | | + mdhd size 32 offset 370
mp4 debug: | | | | + hdlr size 55 offset 402
mp4 debug: | | | | + minf size 310 offset 457
mp4 debug: | | | | | + vmhd size 20 offset 465
mp4 debug: | | | | | + dinf size 36 offset 485
mp4 debug: | | | | | | + dref size 28 offset 493
mp4 debug: | | | | | | | + url size 12 offset 509
mp4 debug: | | | | | + stbl size 246 offset 521
mp4 debug: | | | | | | + stsd size 154 offset 529
mp4 debug: | | | | | | | + avc1 size 138 offset 545
mp4 debug: | | | | | | | | + avcC size 52 offset 631
mp4 debug: | | | | | | + stts size 16 offset 683
mp4 debug: | | | | | | + stss size 16 offset 699
mp4 debug: | | | | | | + stsc size 16 offset 715
mp4 debug: | | | | | | + stsz size 20 offset 731
mp4 debug: | | | | | | + stco size 16 offset 751
mp4 debug: | + styp size 28 offset 767
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @atymic This question is fine and reasonably scoped.  It does belong over on SuperUser.com though.